# How find the maximum of all arrays in an array of arrays?

Tags: d3.js

I'm trying to learn D3 by book and examples. One example I'm working through is a simple (multi) line chart located here http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3884955#index.html .

I can follow along for the most part but I can't make sense of this:

```
y.domain([
  d3.min(cities, function(c) { return d3.min(c.values, function(v) { return v.temperature; }); }),
  d3.max(cities, function(c) { return d3.max(c.values, function(v) { return v.temperature; }); })
]);
```

When I was trying to write the code on my own, using the example as a cheat sheet, I came up with this

```
y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.temperature; })]);
```

because I wanted the y range to span from 0 to the max of all temperatures.

I believe I have two questions here:
1) is the nested mins and maxs because it's looking at the max of each array within the array?
2) am I correct thinking that 'cities' is the entire array and values is the array of temperatures *within* 'cities'?

Apologies if this question isn't very focused. I believe I want to figure out how to find the maximum of an array of arrays.

Comment: I think you mean "looking at the *temperature property* of each *object* within the array". And you shouldnt apologize that your question is unfocused, you should try your hardest to focus it. ;) I suggest you read up on what the `d3.min` and `d3.max` methods do, as well as read up on for example MDN how `object`s and `array`s work.

Comment: Thanks for that info! I have zero experience & knowledge of javascript so googling 'MDN array' yields very helpful info! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Is the nested mins and maxs because it's looking at the max of each array within the array?*

Yes! you are right the cities json is an array which has another array in it with key *values* the idea here is t find the min temperature in this nested array

```
d3.min(cities, function(c) { return d3.min(c.values, function(v) { return v.temperature; }); }),
```

*am I correct thinking that 'cities' is the entire array and values is the array of temperatures within 'cities'?*

Yes you are correct again copy this json below in a json [formatter](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/) you will be able to understand the JSON better:

```
cities = [
   {
      "name":"New York",
      "values":[
         {
            "date":"2011-09-30T18:30:00.000Z",
            "temperature":63.4
         },
         {
            "date":"2011-10-01T18:30:00.000Z",
            "temperature":58
         },
         {
            "date":"2011-10-02T18:30:00.000Z",
            "temperature":53.3
         },
         {
            "date":"2011-10-03T18:30:00.000Z",
            "temperature":55.7
         },
         {
            "date":"2011-10-04T18:30:00.000Z",
            "temperature":64.2
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "name":"San Francisco",
      "values":[
         {
            "date":"2011-09-30T18:30:00.000Z",
            "temperature":62.7
         },
         {
            "date":"2011-10-01T18:30:00.000Z",
            "temperature":59.9
         },
         {
            "date":"2011-10-02T18:30:00.000Z",
            "temperature":59.1
         },
         {
            "date":"2011-10-03T18:30:00.000Z",
            "temperature":58.8
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "name":"Austin",
      "values":[
         {
            "date":"2011-09-30T18:30:00.000Z",
            "temperature":72.2
         },
         {
            "date":"2011-10-01T18:30:00.000Z",
            "temperature":67.7
         },
         {
            "date":"2011-10-02T18:30:00.000Z",
            "temperature":69.4
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

Hope this helps!